# Room, threading and insert/delete queries

Tags: android, android-room

So I know Room does not handle threading so it's up to the dev to ensure it doesnt run queries on the main thread.

Wrapping all queries in AsyncTasks seem incredibly cumbersome but I realize I can use LiveData instead. However, I'm assuming that's only viable for data queries and not Insert and Delete queries? So am I still expected to wrap those in an AsyncTask (without resorting to other third party libraries?) or is there a better option?

Answer (score 5):

> So I know Room does not handle threading so it's up to the dev to ensure it doesnt run queries on the main thread.

Room handles threading if you use `suspend` in Kotlin or a reactive return type for your DAO functions:

- Kotlin `Flow` (requires Room 2.2.0 or higher)
- `LiveData`
- An RxJava type (e.g., `Observable`, `Single`, `Completable`)

If you choose to use none of those things, then yes, threading is up to you.

> Wrapping all queries in AsyncTasks seem incredibly cumbersome but I realize I can use LiveData instead. However, I'm assuming that's only viable for data queries and not Insert and Delete queries?

If you mean `@Query` methods that do an `INSERT` or `DELETE` instead of a `SELECT`, then yes, I think you are correct. Since `@Insert` functions can return a `Long`, though, you might be able to have a `@Query` that uses `INSERT` return a `LiveData<Long>`. I have not tried this and I suspect that the Room compiler will not recognize that approach, but there is always hope. :-)

> So am I still expected to wrap those in an AsyncTask (without resorting to other third party libraries?) or is there a better option?

You are welcome to use an ordinary `Thread`, or an `Executor`, a `JobIntentService`, or anything else in Android that gives you a background thread. `AsyncTask` in particular is obsolete. If you are going to use modern things like Room, use modern things across the board (e.g., Kotlin with coroutines).

Personally, I would recommend `suspend` (for Kotlin developers) or `Completable` (for Java developers using RxJava).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use RxJava

Create an Observable and write your logic inside it. You can subscribe the observable and get the boolean.

```
    public Observable<Boolean> insertUser(User m) {
    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Boolean> e) {
            appDb.userDAO().insertUsers(m);
            e.onNext(true);
            e.onComplete();
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());            

}
```

2. Use Coroutine